# Trouble with converting code from .erb to .haml

Tags: ruby, haml

I started to use **HAML** today and I'm still trying to figure out, how to convert my **ERB** code into an **HAML** file.

This code is supposed to put the single strings of an array (**exAry**) into a select "box" of a form and works as a *.erb* file perfectly fine.

```
<select>
<% @exAry.each do |elem| %>
<option value="<%= elem %>" name="<%= elem %>"> <%= elem %> </option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

So how can I convert this code to **HAML**?

(i know the basics of HAML, I just have trouble with the ruby code in it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%select
  - @exAry.each do |elem|
    %option{:name => elem, :value => elem}
      = elem
```

I'm using [haml convertor](http://html2haml.heroku.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I really like the HAML convertor.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to erb2haml command line tool :

[erb2haml](https://github.com/dhl/erb2haml)